# Unable to change weighted value of WRR record set by cli53

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a WRR record set for www.mydomain.com by console.
Just like:

*mydomain.com www ALIAS XXXXXXXXXXXXX EndpointofELB1 --weight 255 --identifier env1
mydomain.com www ALIAS YYYYYYYYYYYYY EndpointofELB2 --weight 0 --identifier env2*

And, I want to change the weighted values as follow by cli instead of console
.
mydomain.com www ALIAS YYYYYYYYYYYYY EndpointofELB2 --weight 255 --identifier env2
mydomain.com www ALIAS XXXXXXXXXXXXX EndpointofELB1 --weight 0 --identifier env1

I tried cli53 command "rrcreate" just like :

cli53 rrcreate mydomain.com www ALIAS 'Z1XXXXXXXXX EndpointofELB2 .' --weight 255 --replace --identifier env2

cli53 rrcreate mydomain.com www ALIAS 'Z1XXXXXXXXX EndpointofELB1 .' --weight 0 --replace --identifier env1

I got a DNSServerError: 400 Bad Request
"Tried to create resource record set.......
type A cannot be created as other RRSets exist with the same name and type."

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

self response:

solved this by dnscurl.pl 
seems like cli53 cannot do this.

```
dnscurl.pl --keyfile .aws_secrets --keyname=xxxx \
-- -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -X POST \
--upload-file myrequest_route53.xml \
https://route53.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone/YYYYYYYYYY/rrset

while myrequest_route53.xml is the batch file just like:

<ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/">
   <ChangeBatch>
      <Comment>
      This change creates two weighted resource record sets,  each of which has one value.
      </Comment>
      <Changes>
         <Change>
            <Action>UPSERT</Action>
            <ResourceRecordSet>
               <Name>%RECORD_SET%.</Name>
               <Type>A</Type>
               <SetIdentifier>env1</SetIdentifier> 
               <Weight>0</Weight>
               <AliasTarget>
                   <HostedZoneId>%ALIAS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID%</HostedZoneId>
                   <DNSName>%ELB_ENDPOINT_1%</DNSName>
                  <EvaluateTargetHealth>false</EvaluateTargetHealth>
               </AliasTarget>
            </ResourceRecordSet>
         </Change>
         <Change>
            <Action>UPSERT</Action>
            <ResourceRecordSet>
               <Name>%RECORD_SET%.</Name>
               <Type>A</Type>
               <SetIdentifier>env2</SetIdentifier> 
               <Weight>255</Weight>
               <AliasTarget>
                  <HostedZoneId>%ALIAS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID%</HostedZoneId>
                  <DNSName>%ELB_ENDPOINT_2%</DNSName>
                  <EvaluateTargetHealth>false</EvaluateTargetHealth>
              </AliasTarget>
            </ResourceRecordSet>
         </Change>
      </Changes>
   </ChangeBatch>
</ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest>

set value to the following valiables before execute dnscurl.pl
%RECORD_SET%
%ALIAS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID%
%ELB_ENDPOINT_1%
%ELB_ENDPOINT_2%
```